# Ruby On Rails: Order by child attribute

Tags: ruby-on-rails

If I have a model A that has an attribute X and a child model of A called B with an attribute Y, how can I order all the instances of A by Y and X?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm going to use lowercase letters instead:

```
a_instances.sort_by{|a| [a.b.y, a.x]}
```

Comment: thanks, but is there anyway of creating a default scope so it will be sorted automatically?

Answer (score 10):

You can use `default_scope` to order all of your model instances by an association. You just pass the associated model name to the `:includes` param and adjust your order param:

`default_scope :include => 'record', :order => 'records.attribute'`

However, `default_scope` isn't highly recommended. A cleaner approach would be to create a class method in your parent model that you can call from your controllers:

```
def self.all_ordered_by_child
   includes(:records).order('records.attribute DESC')
end
```

You will just need to update all instances that call all records from the parent model.

Comment: thank you Jordan. further question: is there a way of ordering using hashes and without using the direct SQL query?